# adding div to existing 100% height content

Tags: html, css

I have some html...

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="outfit-wrapper">

    <div class="ui-droppable" id="outfit-area"> <!-- drop to this area -->         
        content...
    </div>

    <div id="products-area"> <!-- drag from this area -->
        content...
    </div> <!-- end products-area -->

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Selected relevant parts of css looks like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#outfit-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:98%;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    height: auto !important; /* ie6 ignores !important, so this will be overridden below */
    min-height: 100%; /* ie6 ignores min-height completely */
    height: 100%;    
    border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf; 
    padding:0;
}

#outfit-area {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

#products-area {
    float:right;
    width:40%;
}
```

It works perfectly and outfit-wrapper is 100% of the webbrowsers height. #outfit-area and #products-area fills upp 100% of the #outfit-wrapper div as expected.

Now I want a div with some content at the top of the #outfit-wrapper:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="outfit-wrapper">

    <div id="header">content</div>

    <div class="ui-droppable" id="outfit-area"> <!-- drop to this area -->         
        content...
    </div>

    <div id="products-area"> <!-- drag from this area -->
        content...
    </div> <!-- end products-area -->

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I want the wrapper to have the same height as before, I just want to add the header-div. I need the height of header-div and "#outfit-area and #products-area" to be 100% together. **How do I achieve this? Do I have to add a div-element like this?**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="outfit-wrapper">

    <div id="header">content</div>

    <div id="content-area">

    <div class="ui-droppable" id="outfit-area"> <!-- drop to this area -->         
        content...
    </div>

    <div id="products-area"> <!-- drag from this area -->
        content...
    </div> <!-- end products-area -->

    </div> <!-- end content-area -->

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

For some strange reason - if I set #products-area to position:absolute, then I can't use draggable functionaliy. Please take that in account if you have a good answer to my question :-)

Comment: I've just found the height:auto screwed things up when dealing with heights and percentages. (skip height:auto part if you necessary don't need to develop for ie6!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `<div id="outfit-area">` to `height:100%`, it takes on 100% of the height of the parent element - in this case `<div id="outfit-wrapper">`.

When you add the header, outfit-area is STILL taking 100% of outfit wrapper which now includes the header. You need to either:
A. Give `<div id="header">` a percentage height and then subtract that height from 100% and use this value as the percentage height for `<div id="outfit-area">`, like this:

```
#header {
  height: 10%;
}

#outfit-area {
  height: 90%;
}
```

Edit: Here's a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/CVwCr/

-OR-

B. Nest the header inside of `<div id="outfit-area">` so that it's height isn't being added to ` like so:

```
<div class="ui-droppable" id="outfit-area"> <!-- drop to this area -->
    <div id="header">
      content
    </div>
    content...
</div>
```

Comment: #outfit-area is "left-column" of #outfit-wrapper and #products-area is "right-column" of #outfit-wrapper. So if I do as suggested I would get header only at the left part of screen (60%) - see my css for #outfit-area, I want tje #header to be 100% width - above #outfit-area and #products-area

Comment: You might want to try technique A, then. Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/CVwCr/.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!!! I solved it now. I had "ie6 compability" (height:auto) screwed things up for me. When I hade height:auto then the percentages didn't work as expected (not in FF anyway).